# 74HC5555 triggering

Tags: timer, flipflop

I want to use the [74HC5555](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC5555.pdf) as a long period oscillator for which it seem suited. and I wish to use the internal oscillator (and divider) to determine the Q / not Q transition time of 28 days

The datasheet defines two trigger inputs, one for leading edge trigger, one for trailing edge.

As I am not running the device as a monostable responding to a trigger I/P and wish it to self start on power up and then run continuously, how should the trigger inputs be configured?

To answer Bruces comment below, YES, I want the Q /Q outputs to transition every 28 days, (which works out at an osc freq of approx 7Hz at max division ratio. Comfortably above the internal oscillator 1Hz min frequency rating).

**Solution**

trig A and trig B- No connection.
MR --- 0V.
OSC CON --- +V.
RTR /RTR---0V.
**Note---DO NOT CONNECT C2 AS RECOMMENDED IN THE DATA SHEET, IT INTRODUCES RINGING AT THE INTERNAL OSCILLATOR STATE TRANSITIONS AND CHAOS ON THE Q /Q O/P'S**

Comment: Note that this particular part is in last-time buy status, so hopefully this is a hobby or one-off application.

Comment: Also note that this thing is relatively power-hungry for what it does - 8 µA doesn't seem like much, but a cheaper-per-piece microcontroller (e.g. [STM32F103](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf), as found on the Arduino-compatible "[blue pill](https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F103C8T6-Blue-Pill.html)" Microcontroller boards for < 3€) uses less to keep its RTC running, **and** you describe that you want to use this to have specific behaviour: chances are you really want a microcontroller with an RTC (or just a timer unit and sleep modes), but just don't know it yet.

Comment: _"I wish to use the internal oscillator (and divider) to determine the Q / not Q transition time of 28 days...  and wish it to self start on power up and then run **continuously**"_ - You want an output transition every 28 days?